(Why) are bereitot, especially those not found in the tosefta and midrash halacha considered canonical?
A bereita is a teaching from the time of the Tannaim or before which was not recorded as part of the Mishnah. There are breitot found in the Tosefta and midrash halacha as well as other collections of bereitot, which are no longer extant. Often the talmud will cite a bereita, even not from sources just mentioned, as posing a challenge or contradiction to a Mishnah.
I would like to understand why bereitot, especially those which were not collected in the Tosefta or midrash halacha, were considered canonical at all.
Just like there are works such as the book of the Maccabees which is considered outside the canon of the written Torah, I would expect certain material to be considered outside the canon of the oral torah, such that it would not matter if that material contradicted a Mishnah.
Since it seems this is not the case I would like to understand why, and on whose authority bereitot are considered part of the canon of the oral Torah.

They are outside the canon of the Mishna not the canon of Torah. What do you mean by canonical? What canon?

@DoubleAA Perhaps, canonical in the OP question means their inclusion in gemara. If so, the answer is simple - their mesora was verified.

The premise of the question is that when Rebbi chose to put a teaching in a Mishnah, that gave it authority. The gemarra doesn't assume that. It assumes any accepted teaching from the Tannaim to have authority.

@robev how do you know the teaching in a bereita was actually authored by the tanna and is not mistaken, corrupted, forged etc?

@rikitikitembo I don't know but Chazal knew that the Baraisas they had were accurate, unless they're forced to say otherwise. Then they reject the baraisa.

The Gemara says
אמר ליה ר' זירא לאו אמינא לכו כל מתניתא דלא תניא בי
רבי חייא ובי רבי אושעיא משבשתא היא ולא תותבו מינה בי מדרשא
On this Rashi comments
רבי חייא ורבי אושעיא סדרו את הברייתות ודקדקו בדברי כל חכם לומר כמו שאמר אבל יש תנאים הרבה שמוסיפים על משנתם בדדמי כי הכא
Basically, only Rav Chiya and Rav Oishiya were considered exact enough in there codification of braiysot for it to be considered canon, everything is not is not exact enough to rely upon.

"ודקדקו בדברי כל חכם לומר כמו שאמר" - So they basically verified the accuracy of each beraita's transcript?

this is interesting, but the Stam of the gemarah doesn't seem to comply with this approach

Tosafos in BK (19a) says this as well, and quotes Chullin 141a as his source

As to the fact that the gemara regularly asks questions from other beraisas, I think that we want to trust these beraisas and figure out how they fit with so-and-so's opinion. But we won't treat it as a complete disproof, even if there's no answer.

There were several texts of Oral Law written prior to Mishnah. According to Iggeres Rav Sherira Gaon, (ch. 2) Rebbi mastered 13 approaches to the laws (see also Nedarim 41a).

When Rebbi had mastered 13 approaches to the laws, he taught r. Chiyya 7 of them. Rebbi took ill and forgot them. R. Chiyya restored the 7, but the other 6 were forgotten. There was a launderer who had heard when Rebbe used to recite them. R. Chiyya went and learned them from the launderer. [R. Chiyya] then went and repeated them before Rebbi. When Rebbi used to see the launderer, he would say to him: "You made me and r. Chiyya", According to some, he would say: "You made Chiyya, and Chiyya made me".

Sefer "Kerem Yehoshua" by R.Yehoshua Cohen, p.157-159, when discussing arguments between Rashi and Tosafos, writes the following about the sources of R. Yehudah haNassi's learning:
In the Babylonian Talmud we find that R. Yehudah haNassi had many teachers:

His Father, Rabban Shimon ben Gamliel (Bava Metzia 84b)
R. Yehoshua ben Korcha (same place)
R. Meir (Eruvin 13b in Rashi, contrary to Jerusalem Talmud, Beitza 5:2 (20b); and see Tosafos Menachos 104a, s.v. מוריינא; Rashbam to Bava Metzia 51b, s.v. רברבי; and Maharshal and Rashash there)
R. Elazar ben Shamua (Eruvin 53a, and Menachos 18a)
R. Shimon [b. Yohai] (Shabbos 147b, Rashi to Beitza 26a, s.v. א"ל; Tosafos to Makkos 9b, s.v. נשמט; et. al.)
R. Yehudah [bar Ilai] (Shavuos 13a; and see Megilla 20a)
R. Yose [b. Halafta] (see Tosafos to Shabbos 51a, s.v. אילו)

(Note 7 sources in light with Nedarim 41a!)
Thus, there were other legitimate sources of baraisos, other than Mishna and Tosefta, which differed in scope, logic, and style. The main point is that in Gemara the rabbis tried to cover all bases from all sides, which is why it was called gemara - from גמר - complete.

The Baritot aren't canonical for the purpose of halacha but they could be useful in determining the motivations behind previous rulings.
The Gemara rabbis will often bring an argument like this: Rabbi X ruled like this in a situation.
A response to that argument could be that Rabbi X held by a Barita that we don't follow today.

are there no aggadic beraitot? if a beraita is not canonical, how do we know it is authentic/not a forgery? ie why should we use it as a data source at all?

We know it's authentic because of tradition. We use it as a data point to explain why a Rabbi of yore seems to be saying things that clashes with the established line of thought.

Sometimes there are variant details of stories in the Gemara. They will tell a story and then R'Yehuda will say "I learned that the frog was actually 101 amot tall."

what tradition? if Rebbi didn't include it in the mishna how do we know it has a reliable tradition? I'm thinking of Rebbi as a kashrut certification, a bereita may be kosher (ie have data we can use for discussion) but how do I know if its not certified?

The rabbis kept the tradition of the Baritot in addition to the tradition of the Mishneh. You know it's "certified" because the Gemara who determine the kashrus accept it for certain purposes.
